# how to convert non breaking space to &nbsp; in php

Tags: php

here is my string

```
hello


world



hello world
```

how can I convert this string to

```
hello

&nbsp;

world

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

hello world
```

in php. Any one help please...

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: A simple google search would have answered your question..

Comment: @mfisher91, a search engine would not have told me that there isn't a built-in PHP function to do the job; in fact it landed me here.  From the answer, I gather I need to write my own.  (In my case, I need to ensure date strings are on a single line in a table, to force the table to overflow on small-screen devices, rather than have them wrap.)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to replace every newline to newline + nbsp?

`$out = str_replace(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL.'&nbsp;'.PHP_EOL, $string);`

That is: what is to be deducted from the questions. There are some openings for other answers. For example: what if the next line is not empty?

Comment: hello
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;world
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;hello world

Comment: now here is result:
    
    hello
    &nbsp;
    
    world
    &nbsp;
    
    &nbsp;
    hello world

Comment: Hi #Ivo P it doesn't work properly. Please solved my question...